# ImportError: cannot import name 'ResolveInfo' from 'graphql

Tags: pipe, fastapi, pipenv, starlette, ariadne-graphql

when I ran my main.py file I got

```
ImportError: cannot import name 'ResolveInfo' from 'graphql' (/Users/apple/.local/share/virtualenvs/pythonProject-CGqZmG8Q/lib/python3.9/site-packages/graphql/__init__.py)
```

- However, I am trying to install the following packages but `ariadne` smeas to incompatible with `graphen-core` or `graphen`.

```
uvicorn = "*"
fastapi = "*"
graphene = "*"
starlette = "*"
ariadne = "*"
alembic = "*"
aniso8601 = "*"
appdirs = "*"
asgiref = "*"
black = "*"
click = "*"
colorama = "*"
graphene-sqlalchemy = "*"
graphql-relay = "*"
greenlet = "*"
h11 = "*"
mypy-extensions = "*"
pathspec = "*"
promise = "*"
psycopg2 = "*"
pydantic = "*"
python-dateutil = "*"
python-dotenv = "*"
python-editor = "*"
regex = "*"
singledispatch = "*"
six = "*"
toml = "*"
typing-extensions = "*"
dill = "==0.2.4"
Mako = "*"
MarkupSafe = "*"
Rx = "*"
SQLAlchemy = "*"
```

```
[pipenv.exceptions.ResolutionFailure]: Warning: Your dependencies could not be resolved. You likely have a mismatch in your sub-dependencies.
  First try clearing your dependency cache with $ pipenv lock --clear, then try the original command again.
 Alternatively, you can use $ pipenv install --skip-lock to bypass this mechanism, then run $ pipenv graph to inspect the situation.
  Hint: try $ pipenv lock --pre if it is a pre-release dependency.
ERROR: Could not find a version that matches black (from -r /var/folders/v3/4llt971130g6vvbq53m6k84w0000gn/T/pipenvo1i35v2wrequirements/pipenv-py46372c-constraints.txt (line 24))
Skipped pre-versions: 18.3a0, 18.3a0, 18.3a1, 18.3a1, 18.3a2, 18.3a2, 18.3a3, 18.3a3, 18.3a4, 18.3a4, 18.4a0, 18.4a0, 18.4a1, 18.4a1, 18.4a2, 18.4a2, 18.4a3, 18.4a3, 18.4a4, 18.4a4, 18.5b0, 18.5b0, 18.5b1, 18.5b1, 18.6b0, 18.6b0, 18.6b1, 18.6b1, 18.6b2, 18.6b2, 18.6b3, 18.6b3, 18.6b4, 18.6b4, 18.9b0, 18.9b0, 19.3b0, 19.3b0, 19.10b0, 19.10b0, 20.8b0, 20.8b1, 21.4b0, 21.4b0, 21.4b1, 21.4b1, 21.4b2, 21.4b2, 21.5b0, 21.5b0, 21.5b1, 21.5b1, 21.5b2, 21.5b2, 21.6b0, 21.6b0, 21.7b0, 21.7b0, 21.8b0, 21.8b0
```

I tried to resolve this by removing the version from the `pipenv` file, also I tried using older versions.

- I got stuck in a closed loop, so When I install older version of `graphql-core` it runes fine with ariadne but `graphene` require newer version.
- **Goal**

```
# main.py
import graphene
from fastapi import FastAPI
from starlette.graphql import GraphQLApp

import models
from db_conf import db_session
from schemas import PostModel, PostSchema
import asyncio
import uvicorn
from ariadne import make_executable_schema, SubscriptionType, QueryType
from ariadne.asgi import GraphQL

db = db_session.session_factory()

app = FastAPI()


class Query(graphene.ObjectType):
    all_posts = graphene.List(PostModel)
    post_by_id = graphene.Field(PostModel, post_id=graphene.Int(required=True))

    def resolve_all_posts(self, info):
        query = PostModel.get_query(info)
        return query.all()

    def resolve_post_by_id(self, info, post_id):
        return db.query(models.Post).filter(models.Post.id == post_id).first()


class CreateNewPost(graphene.Mutation):
    class Arguments:
        title = graphene.String(required=True)
        content = graphene.String(required=True)

    ok = graphene.Boolean()

    @staticmethod
    def mutate(root, info, title, content):
        post = PostSchema(title=title, content=content)
        db_post = models.Post(title=post.title, content=post.content)
        db.add(db_post)
        db.commit()
        db.refresh(db_post)
        ok = True
        return CreateNewPost(ok=ok)


class PostMutations(graphene.ObjectType):
    create_new_post = CreateNewPost.Field()


# ariadne copied from https://ariadnegraphql.org/docs/subscriptions

type_def = """
    type Query {
        _unused: Boolean
    }

    type Subscription {
        counter: Int!
    }
"""

subscription = SubscriptionType()


@subscription.source("counter")
async def counter_generator(obj, info):
    for i in range(5):
        await asyncio.sleep(1)
        yield i


@subscription.field("counter")
def counter_resolver(count, info):
    return count + 1


schema = make_executable_schema(type_def, subscription)

query = QueryType()

app.add_route("/", GraphQLApp(schema=graphene.Schema(query=Query, mutation=PostMutations)))
app.mount("/ws", GraphQL(schema, debug=True))

# if __name__ == "__main__":
#     uvicorn.run(app, host="0.0.0.0", port=8000)
```